# To eliminate constants $a$ and $b$ and find corresponding p.d.e

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Eliminate the parameters $a$ & $b$ from the equation $z^2(1+a^3)=8(x+ay+b)^2$ and find corresponding partial differential equation.

here $z$ is function of $x$ & $y$. 
Differentiating with respect to $x$ we get
$$p = \frac{8(x+ay+b)}{z(1+a^3)}$$

& Differentiating with respect to $y$ we get 
$$q =\frac{8a(x+ay+b)}{z(1+a^3)}$$

where $p=z_x$ & $q=z_y$.

Now how should I proceed to eliminate the parameters $a$ & $b$?

Comment: $q/p = a$ will get things started.

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting you. What is your final P.d e?

Comment: Substitute $a = q/p$ back into either expression for the partial derivatives, and calculate $b$ in terms of $p,q,z$. Then replace $a,b$ in the original equation and that's the PDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, when $p\ne0$,

$$a=\frac qp.$$

Then

$$8(x+ay+b)=z(1+a^3)p.$$

Plugging in the initial equation,

$$z^2\left(1+a^3\right)=\frac18\left(z\left(1+a^3\right)p\right)^2,$$
and after simplification
$$8=(1+a^3)p^2$$

or

$$p^3+q^3=8p.$$